# Help with EE Ajax form

Tags: forms, javascript, ajax

I have an ajax form set up for my EE contact form which requires that the email and message field be filled in. I need to have "name" and "subject" required too. Please help

```
 // Contact form to use AJAX.
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        /* helper function to display a message describing the results of the form submit */
        function displayAjaxMessage(message)
        {
            $("#ajax-message").html(message);
            $("#ajax-message").fadeIn(1000);
        }

        /* attach a submit handler to the contact form. By default, EE generates the ID "contact_form" */
        $("#contact_form").submit(function(event) 
        {
            /* stop the contact form from submitting normally */
            event.preventDefault(); 

            /* hide any left over message from a previous submit */
            $("#ajax-message").hide();

            /* send the form data using post and check the results for any errors*/ 
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "/",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "html",           
                data: $(this).serialize(),

                /* If there was some kind of an AJAX error, display an appropriate message or take some other action of your choice */
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    displayAjaxMessage("Sorry, a mistake in form");
                },

                /*  parse the HTML returned by EE to see if they forgot to enter an email address or a message. 
                    If so, the HTML will contain a specific error string we can match, and then we can display our own message */
                success: function(html, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                {
                    if (html.match(/<title>Error<\/title>/)) 
                    {
                        var error = $(html).find('ul li:first').text(); 
                        if (error == "A valid sender email is required")
                        {
                            displayAjaxMessage("Vennligst oppgi en gyldig mailadresse");
                        }
                        else if (error == "Email Message is Required")                  
                        {
                            displayAjaxMessage("Legg inn en melding");                      
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        displayAjaxMessage("Takk for at du kontakter oss");
                    }
                }

            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Umm... obviously you are validating your fields in the back end somehow, so front end code is useless until we see what's going on behind the scenes. I don't even see this AJAXing an ACTion ID... I'm not sure this is even EE related.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can add a name=required[] parameter to each form field you want to make required:

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/email/contact_form.html#required

Answer (score 1):

read much more in details in this site here - http://watabelabs.com/blog/view/submitting-expressionengines-contact-form-with-ajax

Comment: Consider providing the important detail from the link in your answer.  Answers should continue to work as a resource even if that link goes dark.